# `WHERE … IN @xs`, where @xs parameter is a value list: Supported by ADO.NET?

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net, where-in, parameterized-query

I am trying to create a parameterised ADO.NET query with a `WHERE … IN @xs` clause, where `@xs` is a short list of possibly non-contiguous values, for instance `(2, 3, 5, 8, 13)`. Can this be done? If so, how?

This won't work:

```
int[] xs = { 2, 3, 5, 8, 13 };  // I've also tried using a List<int> instead
var c = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand();
c.CommandText = "SELECT … FROM … WHERE … IN @xs";
c.Parameters.AddWithValue("@xs", xs);  // throws ArgumentException due to `values`
```

Neither the [`System.Data.SqlDbType` enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqldbtype.aspx) nor the types in the [`System.Data.SqlTypes` namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.aspx) suggest that this scenario is supported. Must I revert to dynamic SQL (i.e. manually composing the final SQL `CommandText` using string operations)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server 2008 or later, an alternative might be to use "table valued parameters". More info here : [Arrays and Lists in SQL Server 2008
Using Table-Valued Parameters](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2008.html)

Comment: If I understand correctly, this will require **1.** creation of a user-defined table type in the SQL Server database (`CREATE TYPE xsType AS TABLE (x INT)`), **2.** setting the parameter's `SqlDbType` to `SqlDbType.Structured` and `TypeName` to `xsType`, **3.** building a one-column table `@xs` (e.g. in the form of a `IEnumerable<SqlDataRecord>`, and **4.** changing the `IN @xs` to `IN (SELECT x FROM @xs)`. Correct?

Comment: @stakx - 1. yes. 2. you don't always need to set the TypeName (see msdn link). 3. yes, or you can use a DataTable, which (IMO) is simpler 4. yes. Examples : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You will have to build the parameters one at a time:

```
int[] xs = { 2, 3, 5, 8, 13 };
var c = new SqlCommand();
var parameters = xs.Select((x, i) => string.Concat("@xs", i)).ToList();
for (var i = 0; i < xs.Count; i++)
{
    c.Parameters.AddWithValue(parameters[i], xs[i]);
}

c.CommandText = string.Format(
    "SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ... IN ({0})", 
    string.Join(", ", parameters)
);
```

Comment: Is there any advantage in using several parameters `@xs0`, `@xs1`, … instead of just the actual values, if you assume that there are only a few different combinations of concrete values that will ever be used?

Comment: Yes, you should always use parametrized queries. In your specific example with integers it might be safe but otherwise your code becomes vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: So I understand that it was for security reasons, not for performance (SQL Server being able to better cache parameterized commands than non-parameterized ones, or something like that). That answers my question; thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As you already found out: that is not supported.

```
int[] xs = { 2, 3, 5, 8, 13 };
var c = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand();
// this code assumes xs has always at least one item
var s = new StringBuilder("SELECT … FROM … WHERE … IN (@xs0");
c.Parameters.AddWithValue("@xs0", xs[0]);  
for(int i = 1; i < xs.Length; i++)
{
  s.AppendFormat(",@xs{0}", i);
  c.Parameters.AddWithValue(String.Format("@xs{0}",i), xs[i]);  
}
s.Append(")");
c.CommandText = s.ToString():
```

Comment: +1 for giving an explicit answer to my actual question ("Is this supported?"), which the accepted answer doesn't do. I went with the other answer anyway because its code is somewhat simpler and less restricted. Nevertheless: Thanks for a working solution.